# Can i move files to different component in Advanced Installer?

Tags: advanced-installer

I have an Advanced Installer project.
In "Files and Folders" I have 3 folders

Client, Addon, Services.

Now in the "Organisation" of Advanced Installer I dont see the same directories as in files and folders. The files are organized by versioning.
Can i reorganize them or make the folder in "Files and Folders" be recognised so that I can put a condition on installation ?
So I only want to install if the user has selected the check box to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is doable but you should manually configure this in "Organization" view of your Advanced Installer project. Just expand (click on > sign) the current features and components and then just drag and drop the file resources from one component to another.

[- more details about component management in Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/windows-installer-components-and-features.html)

Comment: Worked perfectly.